# how can I fix the error : conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<int>’ requested

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator, g++

I get a error like this :

```
conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<int>’ requested
```

and this a function I get this error from:

```
   vector<int> concat(vector<int> vector1, vector<int> vector2)
{
     return vector1.insert(vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end());
}
```

I used the insert() function from algorithm library.

Comment: Hint: `std::vector<int>::iterator` isn't the same type as `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `insert` returns iterator.

It has the following declaration

```
template <class InputIterator>
iterator insert(const_iterator position, 
                InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

The function interface is not logically consistent.

Either declare the function the following way

```
std::vector<int> & concat( std::vector<int> &vector1, const std::vector<int> &vector2 )
{
    vector1.insert(vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end());
    return vector1;
}
```

or the following way

```
std::vector<int> concat( const std::vector<int> &vector1, const std::vector<int> &vector2 )
{
    std::vector<int> result( vector1 );
    result.insert(result.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end());
    return result;
}
```